# IF ELSE in a stored procedure when you are Creating a #TempTable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am trying to get this stored procedure to only return specific rows when a function equals a specific ID number. For example, `if @RentalOnly = 'Y'` then only return rows where `productID` is in '3367' or '3367G' and `if @RentalOnly = 'N'` then return all other rows that don't have this `productID` in them.

Here is what I have so far.

```
alter Procedure [dbo].GetAllProductIDs
    @StartDate datetime,
    @EndDate datetime,
    @RentalOnly char(1)
AS
begin
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    CREATE TABLE #GetAllProductIDs
    (      
        [Status] nvarchar(30),
        [To Set Date] datetime,
        [Order ID] int,
        [Product ID] nvarchar(10),
        [PPArea] char(2),
        [OrderLineNo] nvarchar(10),
        [OrigSalesman] nvarchar(30),
        [Enterby] int,
        [Rental Month] int,
        [Quantity] int,
        [Quoted$] money,
        [EXT$] money,
        [Mo Base Rental] money,
        [Ext. Base Rental] money,
        [Quoted Mo Rent] money,
        [3367 Total$ vs. Base Total$] money,
        [3367 % Total vs. Base Total] float
    )

    insert #GetAllProductIDs
       exec TempPower_AZ.dbo.GetAllProductIDs @StartDate, @EndDate

    insert #GetAllProductIDs
       exec TempPower_LV.dbo.GetAllProductIDs @StartDate, @EndDate

    insert #GetAllProductIDs
       exec TempPower_OC.dbo.GetAllProductIDs @StartDate, @EndDate

    insert #GetAllProductIDs
       exec TempPower_SD.dbo.GetAllProductIDs @StartDate, @EndDate

    insert #GetAllProductIDs
       exec TempPower_RS.dbo.GetAllProductIDs @StartDate, @EndDate

    if (@RentalOnly = 'Y')
    begin
        Select * 
        from #GetAllProductIDs
        where [Product ID] in ('3367', '3367G')

        return
    end

    if (@RentalOnly = 'N')
    begin
        Select * 
        from #GetAllProductIDs
        where [Product ID] not in ('3367', '3367G')

        return
    end
end
```

Comment: So how about you forget the IF/ELSE and use a `WHERE` clause something like this? `WHERE (@RentalOnly = 'Y' AND productID IN ('3367', '3367G')) OR (@RentalOnly = 'N' AND productID NOT IN ('36367, '3367G'))`

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: What should be returned when @RentalOnly is a value other than 'Y' or 'N' ? Were you asking a *question* or just giving a status report?

Comment: if RentalOnly = 'Y' then only return rows where productID in '3367' or '3367G' and if RentalOnly = 'N' then return all other rows that dont have this productID in them @spencer7593

Comment: And what if @RentalOnly contains the character `'W'` ? Or `'5'` ?  What was the **question** you wanted to ask ? Were you asking a question about the `IF ELSE` syntax for SQL Server ? Were you asking how to return an empty result when @RentalOnly doesn't contain a 'Y' or 'N' ? It's not at all clear **what you are asking**.

Comment: i am asking how do i get it to return rows based on those two values entered into RentalOnly and if nothing is entered it will just return all of the productIDs. And yes the logic i have right now is not returning anything and i am trying to figure out why that is, because the logic in the the if else seems right. @Spencer7593

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: How do i get it to return rows based on those two values ('Y' or 'N') entered into @RentalOnly and if nothing is entered it will just return all of the productIDs

A: To return all of the productIDs, just run a SELECT without a WHERE clause.

But that's conditional on   "if nothing is entered"

What value or values of @RentalOnly would we consider to satisfy the condition  "if nothing is entered"?  Is that condition satisfied by a NULL? a space? a `'W'` ? Any character other than 'Y' or 'N'?

If this is the logic we want to implement:

```
IF @RentalOnly is 'Y', return the specified subset from the table
ELSE IF @RentalOnly is 'N', return a different subset from the table
ELSE (for all other values of @RentalOnly) return the whole table
```

As an example of how to implement that logic using `IF...ELSE` blocks...

```
IF (@RentalOnly = 'Y')
  Select * from #GetAllProductIDs where [Product ID] in ('3367', '3367G')
ELSE
  BEGIN
    IF (@RentalOnly = 'N')
      Select * from #GetAllProductIDs where [Product ID] not in ('3367', '3367G')
    ELSE
      Select * from #GetAllProductIDs
  END
RETURN
```

The `ELSE` isn't strictly necessary. If we code the conditions so that they are are mutually exclusive, we could get an equivalent result with this:

```
IF (@RentalOnly = 'Y')
  Select * from #GetAllProductIDs where [Product ID] in ('3367', '3367G')
IF (@RentalOnly = 'N')
  Select * from #GetAllProductIDs where [Product ID] not in ('3367', '3367G')
IF (@RentalOnly IS NULL OR @RentalOnly NOT IN ('Y','N')
  Select * from #GetAllProductIDs
RETURN
```

As DavidG points out in his answer, it's not strictly necessary to use an `IF` at all. That "if else" logic could be moved into the WHERE clause of a single SELECT statement. For example:

```
Select * from #GetAllProductIDs
 WHERE ( @RentalOnly IN ('Y') AND [Product ID] IN ('3367', '3367G') )
    OR ( @RentalOnly IN ('N') AND [Product ID] NOT IN ('3367', '3367G') ) 
    OR ( @RentalOnly NOT IN ('Y','N') OR @RentalOnly IS NULL )
RETURN
```

Comment: Much more detail than my answer for sure! If I had to guess I'd say the value of `@RentalOnly` will never have another value, but it's good to handle that situation.

Comment: I think OP does want to handle other values, re OP comment "how do i get it to return rows based on those two values entered into RentalOnly and **if nothing is entered it will just return all of the productIDs**. That was included in a comment to the question, it was *not* included in the original question. (If we don't know what the question is, it's difficult to provide an answer to the question being asked.)

Comment: @DavidG: That clarification of the specification was provided *after* you had posted your answer.  I asked a question about that as a comment, asking for clarification. OP posted a comment in response, repeating the incomplete specification, which didn't really answer the question I had asked. I asked *again*, and then OP responded again repeated the same spec, and added the bit about "*if nothing is entered*".

Answer (score 1):

I would drop the `IF`/`ELSE` logic completely and just do it all in a single query like this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM 
    #GetAllProductIDs
WHERE 
    (@RentalOnly = 'Y' AND productID IN ('3367', '3367G')) 
OR  (@RentalOnly = 'N' AND productID NOT IN ('36367, '3367G'))
```

Comment: If the `IF` logic is dropped, then this query will be executed for all values of @RentalOnly. When @RentalOnly is something other than 'Y' or 'N', the query will return will be an empty set. That differs from the original procedure, which doesn't return a resultset. This may be suitable approach for OP. But it's not clear that this answers the question that was asked.

Comment: i have done this and nothing is returning. it is not returning the field names, but does not have any data in the rows? @DavidG

Comment: @ETA So your problem is likely the data in the temp table, not in the logic.